# Android smarphone processor architecture x64 vs x86

Tags: android, cpu-architecture, processor

Will I be able to run x64 applications on an x86 architecture smartphone?  Am I able to create apps for both at the same time? Does this matter at all? for example the Asus Zenfone2 has x86 architecture and most of the other smartphones use x64...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean normal apps written in Java, you do not need to concern yourself with processor architecture at all.

This is only important if you want to create or use native libs (written in C/C++). If you use a native lib your app will only run on devices with architectures for which you provided the lib.